# How to set requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" value in node js code level not in web.config?

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, socket.io-client

Actually i got a issue node.js when am passing query parameters length is too large.so i need put it  requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" in web.config and it is working fine.but in linux environment it can't read from web.config file.

please give me any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.